# Regex to Capture a string

Tags: regex

From the Test string I need to capture, the string `Ec2 Instances which are ... .micro` this string is repeated in my Test string with slight changes.

Like, stopped or running
Instance ID could change

I tried

```
^Ec2 Instances.*micro$
```

But its not working for me.

**Test String**

```
 'ingestionTime': 1526375668364, 'eventId': '34039314519276244324908423608603573165487083445254619137'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]8b2aa0fa731f4534afc62a106ab3aead', 'timestamp': 1526375653280, 'message':"Ec2 Instances which are running:  Instance ID:  i-006690f105487930f Instance state:  {'Code': 16, 'Name': 'running'} Instance type:  t2.micro", 'ingestionTime': 1526375668364, 'eventId': '34039314521038003195592342836784894909026304004227072002'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]8b2aa0fa731f4534afc62a106ab3aead', 'timestamp': 1526375653280, 'message': 'END RequestId: 553e166e-5820-11e8-9bd1-0d6fafd1c3b2', 'ingestionTime': 1526375668364, 'eventId': '34039314521038003195592342836784894909026304004227072003'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]8b2aa0fa731f4534afc62a106ab3aead', 'timestamp': 1526375653280, 'message': 'REPORT RequestId: 553e166e-5820-11e8-9bd1-0d6fafd1c3b2\tDuration: 487.80 ms\tBilled Duration: 500 ms \tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 39 MB\t', 'ingestionTime': 1526375668364, 'eventId': '34039314521038003195592342836784894909026304004227072004'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526389097179, 'message': 'START RequestId: a27ee858-583f-11e8-942c-83f12a7709a7 Version: $LATEST', 'ingestionTime': 1526389097176, 'eventId': '34039614330004076976238280940123439283024120673455898624'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526389097665, 'message': 
       "Ec2 Instances which are stopped:  Instance ID:  i-0ab4e0874254619137 Instance state:  {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'} Instance type:  t2.micro", 'ingestionTime': 1526389097651, 'eventId': '34039614340842239142724163787484244289861010676797800448'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526389097864, 'message': 
       "Ec2 Instances which are running:  Instance ID:  i-006690f2546191374r Instance state:  {'Code': 16, 'Name': 'running'} Instance type:  t2.micro", 'ingestionTime': 1526389097851, 'eventId': '34039614345280087437231757792891484413311004850060001280'}, {'logStreamName': '2018/05/15/[$LATEST]e9c838560b4a43a8beab55c09b8cff61', 'timestamp': 1526389097864, 'message': 
       "Ec2 Instances which are running:  Instance ID:  i-0384972254619137r4 Instance state:  {'Code': 16, 'Name': 'running'} Instance type:  t2.micro
```

Comment: Are you sure these are separate strings/lines? Remove `^` and `$` anchors if not. From your input string, it seems these values are inside double quotes, maybe all you need is replace `^` and `$` with `"`

Comment: yes, these lines comes in between my logs, I removed and tried as you said, but it is matching only first occurence

Comment: What do you mean? How did you use the regex? Where? What method?

Comment: I test it here (https://regexr.com)

Comment: See https://regexr.com/3phbp, all occurrences are matched.

Comment: oops.. seems like some issues with my test string.. https://regexr.com/3ph98 see mine

Comment: Yeah, you forgot to use a regex and the `g` flag. Which all makes no sense at all if you do not know how to use the regex in your target environment. We are not regexr testers here.

Comment: Its my bad :( anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your expected matches are between `"` and `"`. That means, `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string anchor) should be replaced with double quotes.

So, you may consider using

```
/"Ec2 Instances.*?micro"/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regexr.com/3phj9).

Note the use of `*?` quantifier that matches the least amount of any chars between `Ec2` and `micro` as possible to find a valid match.

Also, I added `g` global modifier to enable multiple matching in the regex tester. Whatever environment you are using, you should consult the relevant documentation to learn how to match multiple occurrences of a pattern inside the string.